# Using NGSI Adapter to post updates to Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware-monitoring

I’m trying to use the Monitoring GE / Sextant tool called NGSI Adapter. I am trying to run the command line suggestion from https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-monitoring/blob/develop/README.rst#api-overview

I always get this response:

> time=2016-03-16T11:06:18.794Z | lvl=INFO | trans=ciluqsqi1000077m2u9zwb8x5 | op=POST | msg=Request on resource /check_load with params id=host_1&type=host
>
> time=2016-03-16T11:06:18.800Z | lvl=INFO | trans=ciluqsqi1000077m2u9zwb8x5 | op=POST | msg=Response status 200 OK
>
> time=2016-03-16T11:05:07.004Z | lvl=INFO | trans=ciluqr73e0000umm2nir549ts | op=UpdateContext | msg=Request to ContextBroker at http://orion:1026...
>
> time=2016-03-16T11:05:07.013Z | lvl=INFO | trans=ciluqr73e0000umm2nir549ts | op=UpdateContext | msg=Response status 415 **Unsupported Media Type**

From looking at the release notes to Orion 3.4.1, "Unsupported Media Type" indicates that the Content-Type in the request header is unacceptable. From browsing the code in lib/parsers/common/base.js it seems like NGSI Adapter only currently supports xml. I think that Orion now only supports JSON.

Am I correct that this incompatibility between NGSI Adapter and Orion exists?
When is a fix expected?

Answer (score 0):

You're right.

Taking a look at the [release notes](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/latest), you’ll find that Orion 0.28.0 is the last version which includes XML support (deprecated since 0.23.0).

For that reason, a new **NGSI Adapter v1.4.0** (included as part of [FIWARE Monitoring 5.2.3](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-monitoring/releases/tag/v5.2.3)) has been released. Please follow these [instructions](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-monitoring/tree/v5.2.3#installation) to install it and check documentation at [ReadTheDocs](http://fiware-monitoring.readthedocs.org/en/v5.2.3/).

Thank you for using FIWARE Monitoring.